# Error when adding two large numbers in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code, I am writing a four loop to print the Fibonacci's sequence, to practice using TensorFlow. However, after a few iterations, it makes the numbers negative and then just returns zeros. Why? How can I fix this? It works fine if I use floats by the way. Also, why is this soooo slow compared to a straightforward algorithm?

```
import tensorflow as tf

var1 = tf.Variable(1, tf.int8)
var2 = tf.Variable(1, tf.int8)
temp = tf.Variable(0, tf.int8)

var12 = tf.add(var1, var2)
task1 = tf.assign(var1, var2)
task2 = tf.assign(var2, var12)

task3 = tf.assign(var2, tf.add(var1, temp))

init_op = (tf.initialize_all_variables())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for _ in range(50):
        sess.run(var12)
        sess.run(task1)
        sess.run(task2)
        print(var12.eval(), end=',')
```

Output:
   3,6,12,24,48,96,192,384,768,1536,3072,6144,12288,24576,49152,98304,196608,393216,786432,1572864,3145728,6291456,12582912,25165824,50331648,100663296,201326592,402653184,805306368,1610612736,-1073741824,-2147483648,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

Answer (score 1):

For your main question: It's an issue with how computers store numbers. What you're experiencing here is called an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

The numbers don't fit in the variables, and Tensorflow doesn't try to fix this because that would slow it down (maybe you're used to python handling this for you. `999**999` ftw)

Your variables are of type `int32`, because that's the default.
You're passing `tf.int8` to `tf.Variable`. An `int8` would roll over at 128. But it's landing in the [`Trainable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) parameter.   Switch that to:

```
tf.Variable(1,dtype=tf.int64)
```

`int64` is larger.

Also, that's not the correct sequence. 
It's just doubling the previous element. 
That `sess.run(var12)` doesn't do anything (`var` is a bad name for it, it's not a variable). 
`var12` is automatically re-calculated when you run `task2`.

Why is it slow?

```
> python fib.py
```

It's spending almost all of that time importing Tensorflow, it's big.

Good luck, I hope that helps.